# vba: Offset doesn't work from Word script in Excel doc

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have a Word document that should open an Excel document, find the first empty cell in a range and start filling some cells with information. Herefore I'd like to use Offset, but for some reason it gives an error with Offset. Here's the relevant part of the code:

```
Sub ExcelDoc()

Dim XLapp As Object
Dim objExcelDoc As Object
Dim objOverzicht As Object
Dim c As Range

'Set objOverzicht
Set objOverzicht = ActiveDocument

'Set XLapp and objExcelDoc
Set XLapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
XLapp.Visible = False
Set objExcelDoc = XLapp.Documents.Open("C:\Document.xlsm")

'Set c
Set c = objExcelDoc.Sheets("Overzicht").Range("B3")
    Do
    Set c = c.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop Until c = ""
```

When I run the code, it marks ".Offset" and displays the message "Compile error: Method or data member not found". What am I doing wrong here?

Many thanks in advance for looking into this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Word itself has a "Range" object, so when you declare `Dim c As Range` c is created as Word.Range object, which has no Offset property. So you have 2 ways of solving the problem:

1. Just declare c as Variant: `Dim c as Variant`
2. Make an MS Excel reference and declare variable with it:

   2.1  In VBA Editor go to Tools->References and turn on "Microsoft Excel XX.X Object Library"

   2.2 Declare variable with reference: `Dim c as Excel.Range`